# Google Analytics - Angular 2 - events contain undefined values

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I try to send custom events from an angular 2 app to google analytics

here is the code

```
ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: eventCategory,
    eventLabel: eventLabel,
    eventAction: eventAction,
    eventValue: eventValue
});
```

here is how I call it :

```
this.googleAnalyticsService.sendEvent("testCategory", "testAction", "testLabel", 10);
```

checking the real time view, in the "Events" tab, I see all the events "Event Category" & "Event Action" are "undefined"

I tried to edit the "Google Analytics" tag in Tag Manager and set

```
"category" field to "eventCategory"
"label" field to "eventLabel"
"action" field to "eventAction"
"value" field to "eventValue"
```

but with no luck, can someone help me out?

[edit]

the event is actually not fired at all unless I set values in the tag itself
but how do I get actual values sent from my code ???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxbR6.png)

here are the GA debugger logs :
apparently GA sends an event with "undefined" fields

my own ga.send is sent too, so I dont know why this one does not trigger

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("create", "UA-********-3", {name: "gtm4"})
analytics_debug.js:10 Creating new tracker: gtm4
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm4.set", "&gtm", "G9452W68FS")
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm4.set", "nonInteraction", false)
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm4.set", "hitCallback", [function])
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm4.send", {hitType: "event", eventCategory: "undefined", eventAction: "undefined", eventLabel: undefined, eventValue: undefined})
analytics_debug.js:10 Setting throttling cookie: "_gat_UA-********-3"
analytics_debug.js:10 
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j68d&a=708558753&t=event&ni=0&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2F*******************%2Fa%2Fgifts%3Fs%3D**************************************%26pid%3D14%26m%3D0%26categories%3D%26p%3D0&ul=fr-fr&de=UTF-8&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1903x943&je=0&ec=undefined&ea=undefined&_u=QAGAAAAB~&jid=1225520003&gjid=48267034&cid=804438810.1535016930&tid=UA-********-3&_gid=121630742.1536576429&_r=1&gtm=G9452W68FS&z=461818314

analytics_debug.js:10 <unknown>        (&gtm)  G9452W68FS
analytics_debug.js:10 _j1              (&jid)  1225520003
analytics_debug.js:10 _j2              (&gjid) 48267034
analytics_debug.js:10 adSenseId        (&a)    708558753
analytics_debug.js:10 apiVersion       (&v)    1
analytics_debug.js:10 clientId         (&cid)  804438810.1535016930
analytics_debug.js:10 encoding         (&de)   UTF-8
analytics_debug.js:10 eventAction      (&ea)   undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 eventCategory    (&ec)   undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 hitType          (&t)    event
analytics_debug.js:10 javaEnabled      (&je)   0
analytics_debug.js:10 language         (&ul)   fr-fr
analytics_debug.js:10 location         (&dl)   https://*******************/a/gifts?s=**************************************&pid=14&m=0&categories=&p=0
analytics_debug.js:10 nonInteraction   (&ni)   0
analytics_debug.js:10 screenColors     (&sd)   24-bit
analytics_debug.js:10 screenResolution (&sr)   1920x1080
analytics_debug.js:10 trackingId       (&tid)  UA-********-3
analytics_debug.js:10 viewportSize     (&vp)   1903x943
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("set", "page", "/a/gifts?s=**************************************&pid=14&m=0&categories=&p=0")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("set", "page", "/a/gifts?s=**************************************&pid=14&m=0&categories=&p=0")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("set", "page", "/a/gifts?s=**************************************&pid=14&m=0&categories=&p=0")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("set", "page", "/a/gifts?s=**************************************&pid=14&m=0&categories=&p=0")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("set", "page", "/a/gifts?s=**************************************&pid=14&m=0&categories=&p=0")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("set", "page", "/a/gifts?s=**************************************&pid=14&m=0&categories=&p=0")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)
main.79214c40a0c056e8e45c.106.32125.bundle.js:1 sending to ga Product Details Page Page Displayed Sports & Loisirs 14
analytics_debug.js:10 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "event", {eventCategory: "Product Details Page", eventLabel: "Sports & Loisirs", eventAction: "Page Displayed", eventValue: 14})
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
```

thanks

Comment: It looks like the variables you are referencing are undefined in the context of your ga event. You need to make them available in order for them to be picked up.

Comment: I need to get the "gtm4." tracker name but getAll is not defined when I use : let tracker = ga.getAll()[0];

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
declare let ga: any;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleAnalyticsService {

    public sendEvent(eventCategory: string,eventAction: string,eventLabel: string = null,eventValue: number = null) {
        if(ga && ga.getAll)
        {
            console.log('sending to ga '+eventCategory+' '+eventAction+' '+eventLabel+' '+eventValue);
            let tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
            tracker.send('event', {
                eventCategory: eventCategory,
                eventLabel: eventLabel,
                eventAction: eventAction,
                eventValue: eventValue,
                /*hitCallback : function () {
                  alert("Event received");
                }*/         
            });
        }
        else
            console.warn("GA not ready yet");
    }

    public sendPageView(url:string)
    {
        if(ga && ga.getAll)
        {
            let tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
            tracker.set('page', url);
            tracker.send('pageview');
        }
    }
}
```

care should be taken to call these functions only when your DOM is ready (ngAfterViewInit)

for the "undefined" values they actualy come from the GA tag itself, apparently it is triggering an event automaticaly

so I still dont understand why I would have multiple GA tags for the same web site...